# Concentration bound for sum of indicators of maximum value of k combinations

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, measure-concentration

Let $X_1, \dots, X_n$ be i.i.d. random variables distributed as $\mathrm{Exp}(\lambda)$ for some $\lambda > 0$ and let $t > 0$. For every combination $J$ of $k$ of these variables, we define $Y_J = \mathbf 1 \{ \max_{j \in J} X_j \ge t \}$ where $\mathbf 1 \{ \cdot \}$ is the indicator function. We define

$$S = \sum_{J \in C([n], k)} Y_J$$

where $C([n], k)$ is the set of combinations of the set $[n] = \{ 1, \dots, n \}$ choosing $k$ (i.e. $|C([n], k)| = \binom n k$). Do there exist concentration bounds in the literature for the variable $S$?

Below is a plot of $S$ for $t = \lambda = 1$, $n = 100$, $k = 2$ and $T = 1000$ simulations

[image]

Comment: It seems to me that the sum should expressible simple in terms of the number of r.v.s > t, for example, if n=10 , k=5, and there are 2 r.v.s > t then in order not to get a max > t,  you have to draw all  your samples from the 8 r.v.s < t, and the sum is $10 \choose 5  - 8 \choose  5$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another way to obtain results very similar to those in my other answer here.

Again, by rescaling, without loss of generality $\lambda=1$.

Note that
\begin{equation*}
    S=\binom nk-\binom{n-\nu}k, \tag{0}
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{equation*}
    \nu:=\sum_{j\in[n]}1(X_j\ge t). \tag{1}
\end{equation*}
So,
\begin{equation*}
    S=\mu_n+f_n(\bar V), 
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{equation*}
    \mu_n:=\binom nk-\binom{nq}k, 
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
    q:=1-e^{-t},  
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
    f_n(v):=\binom{nq}k-\binom{n(q-v)}k,
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
    \bar V:=\frac1n\,\sum_{j\in[n]}V_j
\end{equation*}
(so that $n-\nu=n(q-\bar V)$),
\begin{equation*}
    V_j:=1(X_j\ge t)-E1(X_j\ge t)=1(X_j\ge t)-(1-q).  
\end{equation*}
Note that
\begin{equation*}
    \mu_n=\frac{n^k}{k!}\,(1+O(1/n)-q^k)
\end{equation*}
(as $n\to\infty$),
\begin{equation*}
    f_n(v)=\frac{n^k}{k!}\,(1+O(1/n))f(v),\quad f(v):=q^k-(q-v)^k,
\end{equation*}
$f(0)=0$, $f'(0)=kq^{k-1}$,
and the $V_j$'s are iid zero-mean random variables with variance $(1-q)q$.

Now it follows by [Theorem 2.10](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/electronic-journal-of-statistics/volume-10/issue-1/Optimal-order-bounds-on-the-rate-of-convergence-to-normality/10.1214/16-EJS1133.full) that
$S$ is asymptotically normal with (asymptotic) mean $n^k(1-q^k)/k!$ and asymptotic variance $(1-q)q^{2k-1}n^{2k-1}/((k-1)!)^2$.

For $n=100$, $k=2$, and $t=1$, we get $S\approx N(3002,305^2)$, which is in agreement with your picture.

Explicit bounds on the rate of convergence of $S$ to normality can be obtained from [Theorem 2.11](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/electronic-journal-of-statistics/volume-10/issue-1/Optimal-order-bounds-on-the-rate-of-convergence-to-normality/10.1214/16-EJS1133.full).

---

An advantage of this approach is that, (i) by (1), $\nu$ has the binomial distribution with parameters $n$ and $1-q$ and (ii)
by (0), $S=s(\nu)$ for the function
$$\{0,\dots,n\}\ni\mapsto s(x):=\binom nk-\binom{n-x}k\in\{0,1,\dots\},$$
and the function $s$ is strictly increasing on the set $\{0,\dots,n-k+1\}$ (and equals the constant $\binom nk$ on the set $\{n-k+1,n-k+2,\dots,n\}$, which is relatively small if $n$ is much greater than $k$). So,
\begin{equation}
    P(S\ge s(x))=P(\nu\ge x)\text{ for any $x\in\{0,\dots,n-k+1\}$}. 
\end{equation}
Thus, any one of the many upper or lower bounds on the tail probabilities of a binomial distribution results in the corresponding upper or lower bound on the tail probabilities of $S$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your very detailed answer! (and the other approach as well!)

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\si}{\sigma}\newcommand{\Si}{\Sigma}$By rescaling, without loss of generality $\lambda=1$.

The random variable
\begin{equation}
    U_n:=\frac{S-ES}{\binom nk}=\frac1{\binom nk}\sum_{J\in\binom{[n]}k}(Y_J-EY_J)
\end{equation}
is a [U-statistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/U-statistic). Therefore, for each natural $k\ge2$, by Hoeffding's [Theorem 7.1](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-mathematical-statistics/volume-19/issue-3/A-Class-of-Statistics-with-Asymptotically-Normal-Distribution/10.1214/aoms/1177730196.full), $U_n$ is asymptotically normal (as $n\to\infty$) with (asymptotic) mean $0$ and asymptotic variance $k^2\si_1^2/n$, where
\begin{equation}
    \si_1^2:=Var\,g(X_1),\quad g(X_1):=E(Y_{[k]}|X_1). 
\end{equation}
In our case,
\begin{equation}
    g(x)=1(x\ge t)+1(x<t)(1-q^{k-1}),\quad q:=1-e^{-t}, 
\end{equation}
and hence
\begin{equation}
    \si_1^2=1-q+q \left(1-q^{k-1}\right)^2-\left(1-q^k\right)^2=(1-q)q^{2k-1}. 
\end{equation}

It is easy to see that $ES=\binom nk (1-q^k)$.

Thus, $S$ is asymptotically normal with (asymptotic) mean $ES=\binom nk (1-q^k)$ and asymptotic variance $\Si^2:=\binom nk ^2 k^2\si_1^2/n$.

For $n=100$, $k=2$, and $t=1$, we get $S\approx N(ES,\Si^2)$ with
$ES\approx2972$ and $\Si:=\sqrt{\Si^2}\approx302$, which is in agreement with your picture.

Explicit bounds on the rate of convergence of $U_n$ to normality (obtained using Stein's method) are available -- see [Chen and Shao, Theorem 3.1](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/bernoulli/volume-13/issue-2/Normal-approximation-for-nonlinear-statistics-using-a-concentration-inequality-approach/10.3150/07-BEJ5164.full).